# How Convert system.data.dataRow value to integer

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable

I faced a problem when getting datarow value and convert to integer. The function will retrieve data and count from database through datatable method. I success get the count value and I want to use the value for calculate the employee absence day.

```
 Dim table As New DataTable
 Dim AttendCommand As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID) AS AttendDay FROM employee.attendance WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID AND month=@month", MysqlConn)
    MysqlConn.Open()
    AttendCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", txtID.Text)
    AttendCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", Cmonth)
    Dim adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(AttendCommand)
    adapter.Fill(table)

    If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        test = CInt(table.Rows(0).ToString)

    End If
    MysqlConn.Close()
    'count absence day after retrieve
    Dim countTotal As Integer = 0
    Dim total As Integer = 22
    countTotal = total - test
```

The result I get from debug is countTotal=0.

Comment: You dont need a DataAdapter and DataTable for that query.  `rows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar)` will work.  Be sure there is matching data

Answer (score 1):

@Plutonix thank you so much for suggestion,I manage to get the value.

```
 Dim test As Int32 = 0
  Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        test = Convert.ToInt32(AttendCommand.ExecuteScalar)
        counTotal = total - test
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

I also identify the problem why I not manage to get the total value through dataTable method. (.Item(0) is missing)

```
  If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        test = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString)


    End If
```

Both methold could get the total value